# Outlook Add-in insertion at the end

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm trying to insert a HTML formatted text at the end of the just before the  tag.

So, while this works (insert a whole new text)  :

```
        String sHtml;
        sHtml = "<HTML>\n" +
           "<HEAD>\n" +
           "<TITLE>Sample GIF</TITLE>\n" +
           "</HEAD>\n" +
           "<BODY><P>\n" +
           "<h1><Font Color=Green>Inline graphics</Font></h1></P>\n" +
           "</BODY>\n" +
           "</HTML>";

        mail.HTMLBody = sHtml;
```

This fails when i try to insert at the end of body:

```
        String sHtml;

        sHtml = "<P><h1><Font Color=Green>Inline graphics</Font></h1></P>\n</BODY>\n";
        mail.HTMLBody.Replace("</BODY>", sHtml);
```

Please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the last line into:

```
mail.HTMLBody = mail.HTMLBody.Replace("</BODY>", sHtml);
```

Comment: K, i changed "</BODY>" to "</body>" and now it works !  Thank you!

Comment: You might want to consider changing the body tag before filling it into the mail.HTMLBody. Sounds like the HTML is being parsed after it is filled, which can cause unexpected results like the tag being converted to lowercase.